# Second covariant derivative, computation problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, curvature, differentiation, covariance

I am having a question on the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_covariant_derivative

Using the notation therein I don't get why
$(\nabla_{u}\nabla_{v}w )^a=u^c\nabla_{c}v^b\nabla_{b}w^a$.

It is clear that $(\nabla_{u}\nabla_{v}w )^a=(u^c\nabla_{c}v^b\nabla_{b}w)^a$.

Developping this I get a term $u^c\nabla_{c}v^b\nabla_{b}w^a$ for the $a^{th}$ basis vector , but also many other terms.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Looking at the wikipedia page, it looks like the parentheses are used in a sloppy way. At least the first two equalities make sense when the parenteses are used like you do, and in fact the a doesn't play any role and can be omitted.

Comment: Ok, but after ''It is also straightforward to verify that'' to get the third equation I need apparently that $(u^c\nabla_{c}v^{b})\nabla_{b}=\nabla_{\nabla_{u}v}$, which cannot be explained by sloppy notation... For me $(u^c\nabla_{c}v^{b})\nabla_{b}=\nabla_{(\nabla_{u}v^{b})b}=\nabla_{\nabla_{u}v-b^{v}\nabla_{u}b}$. I  must misunderstand something.

Comment: Agreed. It would be straightforward if instead of $(u^c \nabla_c v^b) \nabla_b w$ it would have been $(u^c \nabla_c v)^b \nabla_b w$.

Comment: It's abstract notation - there are no vectors - there are no tangent vectors and no co-tangent vectors. What does it mean to take the covariant derivative in the direction of the abstract index 3 - e.g., $\nabla_{b}w$?

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake is in assuming that there are other terms. The way I see it, your only vector quantity is $w$, $u_{c} \nabla^{c} $ for example is a sum/scalar and doesn't have any vector character or components, thus does not need to be expanded into base vectors.